# Failed to install ntp via apt-get in Debian

Tags: debian, apt, ntp

When trying to install `ntp` (because my server clock is wrong), it just pukes this massive error. Any idea how to fix this?

```
root@pan-prodweb01:~# apt-get install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ntp is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up ntp (1:4.2.6.p2+dfsg-1+b1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99obmaua' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'S99obmscheduler' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'obmscheduler' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'obmaua' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 8
insserv:  loop involving service nfs-common at depth 7
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$aconfigured to not write apport reports
ll' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmaua depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting obmscheduler depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service tomcat6 at depth 9
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 10
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and checkroot if started
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 5
insserv:  loop involving service hostname at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service kbd at depth 12
insserv:  loop involving service module-init-tools at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountoverflowtmp if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountoverflowtmp at depth 9
insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 8
insserv: There is a loop at service obmaua if started
insserv: There is a loop between service obmaua and ifupdown-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service ifupdown-clean at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop at service stop-bootlogd if started
insserv:  loop involving service obmaua at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service mtab at depth 7
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing ntp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ntp
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/locale: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/man: 0 KiB

Total disk space freed by localepurge: 0 KiB

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix the problem with your backup init scripts. You may need the assistance of the vendor to fix this.

Once those are fixed, you should be able to complete the installation with `apt-get -f install`.

The Vendor has put up a help page for this issue, and the fix is to add the LSB headers to the init scripts for the OBM scripts.

ADDED

Ahsay furnishes [instructions here](https://help.ahsay.com/display/2/articleDirect/index.aspx?aid=2752&link=)

Comment: What are the backup init scripts?

Comment: obmaua and obmscheduler. You couldn't possibly have missed them in the output you posted.

Comment: Yea I saw them, I just didn't know what the were.